# SQL Select Query Error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing, jtable

Here I have have a table

> expenses

with columns

- id (PK)
- type_id (FK)
- amount
- date
- vehicle_id (FK)

In my *jtable* I want to show it like this [image]

I used this sql code the

`SELECT vehicle_id,SUM(amount) FROM expenses GROUP BY type_id;`

And I got output as

[image]

But I want it like previous image (the long one).. What can I do to this ?

**Note**

Here I used *Sum* for get multiple *amount* values.*type_id* used to denote various expenses type like diesel, oil, service..

Comment: how did your second picture become the output of that select statement which only returns 2 columns ?

Comment: I don't know. When I do it Navicat, it also shows the same output. Any thing wrong ?

Comment: Since it's more SQL question than Java or UI I would advise to add `sql` tag to list of tags. About question: did you consider using `left join`s in your SQL query?

Comment: No. I have no idea about it..Can't we get it from a SELECT query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using *conditional aggregation*:

```sql
SELECT vehicle_id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN type_id = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Diesel,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type_id = 2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Insurance,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type_id = 3 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Tyre,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type_id = 4 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Battery,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type_id = 5 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Oil,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type_id = 6 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Garage
FROM expenses 
GROUP BY vehicle_id;
```

You need to `GROUP BY` *only* `vehicle_id`. Then perform conditional `SUM` operations depending on `type_id`. This way you can get partial sums for `type_id` per `vehicle_id`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da8be/1)

Comment: thank you very much..It works nicely..I fed up with this since 5 days..thank you very much again..